# Access file using hex value with open()

Tags: c, hex, mips, cgi

I am reversing a MIPS .cgi with ghidra which has an external function call. I opened that library file to view the function decompilation and it was using the open() function with a hex value instead of path... How can I resolve that value to an exact path or a location in memory or something?
The exact line from ghidra:

```
local_10=open((char *)0x2060,0)
```

Comment: At the location `0x2060` in memory, there's a null-terminated string. You need to look at that position in memory.

Comment: The .cgi is on my router so how do I access that address in memory

Comment: just dump the .cgi binary. You must have it else you could not decompile it right?

Answer (score 0):

(char*)0x2060 is a pointer to memory address 0x2060. The first letter of the string should located there.